# why the code produces the output -511

Tags: java, int

consider the code:

```
public class Test
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = -0777;
        System.out.printf("%d",i);
    }
}
```

The code produces the output -511, i was expecting it to be -777

Comment: you can indent code to make it `code` style. don't use backticks for every single word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-0777` with a `0` prefix means that the number is in octal.

`-777` in octal is `-511` in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

`-0777` means the number is octal. So,

```
-(7*(8^2)+7*(8^1)+7*(8^0))
```

Which is `-511` inn decimal